# use loop to determine if number is valid c#

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to ask the user to enter a number from 2-12. I want to use a loop to check if valid, but am having trouble only displaying the result once.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number between 2 and 12");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

bool isValid = true;
for(int p = 2; p < 13; p++)
{
    if(p > x)
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else 
        isValid = false;

    if(isValid == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is good", x);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("not valid");
}
```

Comment: move the second `if/else` outside the loop, unless you want to point out that `x` is/isn't valid 10 times...

Comment: Is it exercise about using `break`? (which should be placed in `isValid=false` branch of `if`)

Answer (score 1):

Why you need loop to check value from range ?

Try like this

```
if(x>=2 && x<=12)
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is good", x);
else
  Console.WriteLine("not valid");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use a loop for this?

You could check if the number is between 2 and 12 by doing this instead:

```
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

bool isValid = true;
if (x < 2 || x > 12)
{
    isValid = false;
}
```

Otherwise, if you still want to do your loop, you can try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 2 and 12");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

bool isValid = false;
for(int p=2; p<13; p++)
{
    if(x == p)
    {
        isValid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(isValid==true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is good", x);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not valid");
}
```

**Edit:**

Also just a suggestion but you should be careful with using `Parse`.  If you use `Parse` and the user enters a non-numeric character or enters a number bigger/smaller than the allowed values for `int`, your app will stop with a `FormatException` error.

To fix this, you can use `TryParse` instead like this:

```
int x;
bool result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);

if (result)
{
    // Put your for loop or if statement here
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid number was detected.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to validate if the number fall within the range 2-12 you should remove your loop and use this instead

```
bool isValid = true;
if (x < 2 || x > 12) {
    isValid = false;
}
```

or simply

```
bool isValid = x >= 2 && x <= 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? There's a flaw in the logic on the sample above, where you only ask once, and then loop `10` times. To simplify you can loop and then ask for the user input until `0` is entered and the loop will exit.

Sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number between 2 and 12. (0 to exit)");
        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (x >= 2 && x <= 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is good", x);
        }
        else if(x != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not valid", x);
        }
    } while (x != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number between 2 and 12: ");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
bool isValid = (2 <= x && x <= 12);
Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}valid", x, isValid ? "" : "not ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number between 2 and 12");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (!Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Contains(x))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Its not Good\n",x);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Its  Good\n",x);
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit..");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```